# C programming trie tree insert

Tags: c, tree, insert, trie

I just started programming and have a beginner question,I am writing a trie insert function that insert a string into the trie tree. But when I add a string with more than two characters I'm getting heap buffer overflow. Here is my insert function:

```
struct node* insert(struct node *root,char *c){
int i=0;
struct node *temp=root;
while(c[i]){
int index=c[i]-'a';
//New Node
struct node *n=malloc(sizeof(*n));
n=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
temp->child[index]=n;
i++;
temp=temp->child[index];
}
return root;
};
```

The definition of the tree node

```
struct node
{   
int isword;
int prefix;
int occurrence;
int leaf;
struct node * child[26];
};
```

and How I called them

```
char *c=malloc(3*sizeof(char));
c[0]='a';
c[1]='d';
c[2]='e';
struct node *root=malloc(sizeof(*root));
root=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
insert(root,c);
```

I think it's how I allocate space in the insert function for new node that went wrong, but I'm not sure what's the proper way to avoid heap buffer overflow, any advice please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c` is not ending with nul. So c[i] is undefined if `i>=3`(maybe coredump because access invalid memory address). `while(c[i])` may run more than 3 times. This maybe the point.

```
char *c=malloc(3*sizeof(char));
c[0]='a';
c[1]='d';
c[2]='e';
```

btw, code below will cause memory leak:

```
struct node *root=malloc(sizeof(*root));
root=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Comment: So I should do something like c[3]='\0';?

Comment: and for allocating memory, is it suppose to be  struct node * root = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
 instead?

Comment: @GhostKidYao 1. yes, but why not  `char *c="ade";`, since `c` is  readonly?  2. yes.

Comment: Thanks! 1. Because I want to a file character by character to make sure it's alphabet and add it to the string. so I have to add it one by one.

Comment: @GhostKidYao Then you may accept the answer to mark this question as solved, as it may be helpful for others.

Comment: damn I almost forgot. My fault